# Modify gnome-flashback panels in ubuntu 20.04 LTS from the terminal

Tags: 20.04, gnome-panel, gsettings, gnome-flashback

I have a fresh installation of 20.04 LTS, I have installed `gnome-flashback` with:
`sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback -qq`
After logging in in the `gnome-flashback` Xsession I would like to execute three actions from the command line:

1. Remove the whole bottom panel
2. Add a Trash icon to the top panel (placed at the left, before the left-bar)
3. Add "Window List" to the top panel (placed at the right, after the main menu)

Screenshot of a virtual machine with desired output:

[image]

I think this should be possible to achieve with `gsettings`, right?
I have been playing around with manual adjusting the panel elements and simultaneous inspecting the changes with `dconf watch /`, however, I was not able to replicate the commands that would lead to the desired acion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to start with existing layout file - `/usr/share/gnome-panel/layouts/ubuntu.layout`. Copy that layout as `my-layout.layout` in same directory.

Edit layout file to match your needs:
- Remove whole `[Toplevel bottom-panel]` group;
- Remove `[Object show-destkop]` group;
- Remove `[Object workspace-switcher]` group;
- Under `[Object window-list]` group change `toplevel-id` from `bottom-panel` to `top-panel`;

Above should give you only top panel with `menu-bar`, `window-list` and `indicators` applets.

To add trash applet you will need following changes:
- Make sure `gnome-applets` are installed;
- Add new group:

```
[Object trash]
object-iid=TrashAppletFactory::TrashApplet
toplevel-id=top-panel
pack-type=end
pack-index=1
```

When layout file is ready do following things:
- `gnome-panel --replace &` to "detach" panel from `session`;
- `killall gnome-panel` to kill/stop it. Without above it will be restarted automatically.
- `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/gnome-panel/` to remove existing configuration;
- Change default layout with `gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-panel.general default-layout "my-layout"`.

Now you can restart panel with `gnome-panel &` or reboot. You should get your layout if I have not made some mistake. Sorry, this is untested!

Comment: Almost ideal! Cannot accept the answer yet since it puts TrashApplet as the leftmost element in the top panel, unlike in the picture I posted...

Comment: I worked it out - I think you should have `pack-type=end` and `pack-index=4` in the Trash Applet

Comment: Updated. `pack-index` starts with 0 for each pack type.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just right-click on the panels while holding down Super+Alt.....?

:)

More specifically:

1. Super+Alt+right click on bottom panel --> remove panel.
2. and 3. Super+Alt+right click on upper panel --> add to panel --> select Trash and (I believe) Windows List or Window Switcher applet, it should be one of those two.

If youve chosen the wrong one --> Super+Alt-right click on applet icon --> delete applet.

To move an applet icon, Super+Alt+right click --> change position.

HTH :)

Comment: Thank you, but you missed the "from the terminal" part of the question, which is crucial here ;)

Comment: boom! it works now :)